# NoRverseMatch Error when linking relative urls to views in django 1.9 templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using the view-callables in my app.urls because I keep getting warnings that app.views.view_name is being deprecated

```
app.urls
from .views import (
post_list,
post_detail,
post_create,
post_edit,
post_delete,
recent_posts,
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', recent_posts, name='recent_posts'),
    url(r'^post/$', post_list, name="list"),
    url(r'^post/create/$', post_create, name="create"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name="detail"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_edit, name="edit"),
    url(r'^post/delete/$', post_delete, name="delete"),

    ]
```

Here is my project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include ("blog.urls", namespace="post")),
]
```

here's the template:

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
   <nav class="menu">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'app.views.view_name' %}">All Posts</a></li>
           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'app.views.another_view_name' %}"> Create Post </a></li>
           {% endif %}
       </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

This is what I have had to use but it's also bad, probably worse

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
   <nav class="menu">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'app.views.view_name' %}">All Posts</a></li>
           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'app.views.another_view_name' %}"> Create Post </a></li>
           {% endif %}
       </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Please any ideas on how to represent urls to my views in the templates? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the namespace name,in your case 'post' followed by colon (:) then view_name e.g to list all posts:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'post:list' %}">All posts</a><li>
```

You can read more on how to handle urls in django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: You're welcomed. Hopefully through the django docs you have also noted how to pass arguments to the detailed view through the url tag.

Comment: Not so much. Still trying to assimilate the technical terms that keep jumping in my face

Answer (score 0):

You want to link to the relevant URL using the url `name` that you declare in your `urls.py` file. So, your template should probably look like:

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
   <nav class="menu">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'list' %}">All Posts</a></li>
           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'create' %}"> Create Post </a></li>
           {% endif %}
       </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```